# NSTableRowView selected row background colour

Tags: swift, nstableview, nsprogressindicator

I have a custom table row view that lets me set the background colour of the selected row:

```
import Cocoa

class MyRowView: NSTableRowView {

    override func drawSelection(in dirtyRect: NSRect) {
        NSColor.black.setFill()
        dirtyRect.fill()
    }
}
```

This works fine for any columns containing NSTextFields, where I have been able to set the background colour to transparent in the storyboard but for columns where I have an NSButton or an NSProgessIndicator, the background of those objects show the same as for unhighlighted rows. You can see in the image below that unselected rows are vibrant dark, showing what is underneath the window. Selected rows should be black, but the checkbox still has a vibrant dark look to it.

[image]

I have managed to solve this issue for the button with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40576392/nsbutton-set-background-color-macos-10-12), but this doesn't work for the progress indicator. i've tried subclassing NSProgressIndicator and just calling the superclass's init and draw methods, but it doesn't work:

```
class MyProgInd: NSProgressIndicator {
    override func draw(_ dirtyRect: NSRect) {
        super.draw(dirtyRect)
    }

    required init?(coder decoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: decoder)
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean "columns containing NSTextFields" and "the superclass's draw method"?

Comment: yes on both counts - i've now edited to correct those points